Object detection for finite dataset
Consider the following scenario

If I want to train a model to detect and count these squares:

These squares will never be different. They will always look exactly the same, and be of exactly the same size, and never have some kind of overlap or obstacle in the way, nor change color etc. - they will always be exactly the same.
But training on this same image over and over (because what other image to make a dataset will you use? it never changes), it doesn't identify the boxes properly. And if you take the image and make distorted versions so that you can have a dataset, it still doesn't help.
How do I go about training an algorithm for such a simple scenario? Or can object detection (or classification, if we include the flagged ones, so we would have 2 classes) only work for things that can "change/distort visually" but not for something that is always the same?
I've been trying to find literature, papers and articles about it, but I don't know what this problem is called.

Since you say "training", it sounds like you're using a machine learning method, like a convolutional neural network. A major reason for using these types of algorithms is that they can generalize: if you show it enough dogs (etc), it can recognize other dogs that are not in the training set, are lit differently, etc. That generalization can be handy, but it comes at a steep price: you need more data and compute, plus the model's behavior is harder to interpret.
If you don't need that flexibility, there are simpler solutions. One of the simplest is template matching. Imagine that you are sliding the "template" (here, your empty square) across the larger image, moving it one pixel at a time. At each location, you calculate the similarity between that template and the underlying patch of the image (e.g., by computing the correlation between the two, etc). Whenever that similarity is sufficiently high, you report a "match" (i.e., the template is present).
When the template (or image) are self-similar, naive implementations might erroneously detect the same target at several nearby locations: for example, the similarity values will be quite...uhh...similar... for a template that's perfectly centered over an empty box and one that's shifted a pixel to left. The usual solution for this is some form of non-maximum suppression, which chooses only the single strongest match within some neighborhood. (However, on a purely digital image, this may not be a problem).
It's also not necessary to actually slide-and-correlate the template one pixel at a time. Phase correlation does something conceptually similar by operating in the frequency domain. This SO answer contains demos in Matlab and Python, which may be helpful.
In general, these "old school" computer vision methods may feel a little hacky but they can work astonishingly well with a little bit of careful tuning and evaluation.
